# How to link to a page and have a specific tab active with rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

If an info page has multiple tabs based on different topics and there are links leading to the info page from different pages, how do you link to the info page with an active tab depending on the link used?

I want to have a link like this:

```
<p>View the terms & conditions on our info page <%= link_to "here", info_path %>, thanks.</p>
```

Lead to my info page with the `Terms` tab active like this:

```
<li role="presentation">
  <a href="#terms" class="active" aria-controls="terms" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">
    <h2>Terms</h2>
    <p>These are the terms.</p>
  </a>
</li>
```

I was wondering how to change the "active" status based on the link from a different page on my site. Does the active status need to be changed on the specific `tabpanel` instead? Thank you!

This is the tab section from the info page:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
  <li role="presentation">
    <a href="#about" aria-controls="about" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">
      About
    </a>
  </li>

  <li role="presentation">
    <a href="#advertise" aria-controls="advertise" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">
      Advertise
    </a>
  </li>

  <li role="presentation">
    <a href="#legal" aria-controls="legal" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">
      Legal
    </a>
  </li>

  <li role="presentation">
    <a href="#privacy" aria-controls="privacy" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">
      Privacy
    </a>
  </li>

  <li role="presentation">
    <a href="#terms" aria-controls="terms" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">
      Terms
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>

<!-- TAB PANES -->
<div class="tab-content" id="infoTabContent">
  <!-- TAB DIVIDER -->
  <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade in" id="about">
    <h3>About</h3>
    <div class="indent">
      <p>This is the about tab using a div to indent lines</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- TAB DIVIDER -->
  <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade" id="advertise">
    <h3>Advertise</h3>
  </div>
  <!-- TAB DIVIDER -->
  <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade" id="legal">
    <h3>Legal</h3>
  </div>
  <!-- TAB DIVIDER -->
  <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade" id="privacy">
    <h3>Privacy</h3>
  </div>
  <!-- TAB DIVIDER -->
  <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade" id="terms">
    <h3>Terms</h3>
  </div>
  <!-- TAB DIVIDER -->
</div><!-- Tab Content -->
```

Comment: Show us your info page code.

Comment: @Pavan I just added in the tab section from my info page, thanks for asking!

Answer (score 3):

You can pass params on `link_to` method. Something like:

```
link_to "here", info_path(active_tab: "your_active_tab_name")
```

So, in your info page view, you can try to retrive it from `params[:active_tab]`, so you can set your active attribute based on that value.
Hope this helps, good luck

EDIT:
If you're using bootstrap tabs (https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_ref_js_tab.asp), you can set some tab as active by adding the active class to the "li" element, like this:

```
  <li role="presentation active">
    <a href="#advertise" aria-controls="advertise" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">
      Advertise
    </a>
  </li>
```

So, wherever you put a link to that info page, you should pass a param that indicates which tab will be active, something like this:

```
link_to "more info", info_path(active_tab: "advertise")
```

Then, on your info page, you check the params[:active_tab] to determine which tab will be active. Something like:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
  <li role="presentation #{params[:active_tab]=='about' ? 'active' : '' }">
    <a href="#about" aria-controls="about" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">
      About
    </a>
  </li>

  <li role="presentation #{params[:active_tab]=='advertise ? 'active' : '' }">
    <a href="#advertise" aria-controls="advertise" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">
      Advertise
    </a>
  </li>

   ... and so it goes on

</ul>
```

Hope this makes it clear! Also, has to test it, but think this works

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer, but I don't understand what you mean by retrieving from `params[:active_tab]`. Is this something I would need to make a method or would it simply be added to the tab pane/tab button on the info page? Thanks!

Comment: since you call the method link_to as I described above, the "active_tab" will be a param that you can retrieve on view. So, on your info page, you can access that value with the params[:active_tab]. So you can call the method like 'link_to "here", info_path(active_tab: "privacy")', for example. And on your view, you can get that value on params[:active_tab] variable and set "privacy" as shown tab. Hope this makes it clear

Comment: I have to ask, could you provide some code? I really don't know where I'm supposed to include the params[:active_tab].

Comment: @Jake updated the code with an example. Has to test it, but some approach near that should work

Comment: I tested this code and also tried putting the `#{params[:active_tab]=='advertise ? 'active' : '' }` section on each of my tab-panes with their respective `params` and did not work either way. If you could find a solution to this it would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I've tried with a bit of Javascript.

Add an identifier to your `li` element inside the `ul.nav.nav-tabs`, this way it could be easily reached with the params sent, like:

```
<li role="presentation" id="terms-li">
  ...
</li>
```

Then, the same for your `div` tag with `role="tabpanel"`, like:

```
<div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade" id="terms-tab">
  ...
</div>
```

Then in the previouse view, you can add a `link_to` helper, passing the tab you want to make active, like:

```
<p>
  View the terms & conditions on our info page 
  <%= link_to 'here', root_path(tab: 'terms') %>, thanks.
</p>
```

Then in the view where are the tabs, add an script which take the `params[:tab]` and check if they're sent or not, if so then get your `li` and `div` elements, remove the class `active` from the first `li` and add active to the new elements:

```
<script>
  if ('<%= params[:tab] %>' !== '') { 
    let params = '<%= params[:tab] %>',
        li = document.getElementById(params + '-li'),
        tab = document.getElementById(params + '-tab'),
        ul = document.querySelectorAll('ul.nav.nav-tabs > li')[0].classList,
        div = document.querySelectorAll('div.tab-content > div')[0].classList

    ul.remove('active')
    div.remove('in', 'active')
    li.classList.add('active')
    tab.classList.add('in', 'active')
  }
</script>
```

Make sure the id `terms-tab` and all the identifiers for each div with role `tabpanel` are equal to the href attributes in their `anchor` tags.

You can see [here](https://immense-ravine-54825.herokuapp.com/) a working demo.

Comment: I implemented your strategy in my links, yet it doesn't open any tab when the link is pressed. It only links to the URL with #terms at the end. Any reason why it's not opening the tab based on the link pressed? Thanks!

Comment: It works well with the about tab (default as active, and without active), but even after I integrated this code into all other links and tabs it only loads the about tab, all others simply load empty tabs but have the tab selected. Then all of the other tabs dont load when their tab is pressed, needing the URL to be re-entered as the default url for the info page.

Comment: Well, after a bunch of time looking at the problem, it was, as I changed the id of the element to `terms-tab`, then the anchor is also pointing to that, try instead `#terms-tab` in the anchor inside the `li` element.

Comment: I tried out your updated code but I noticed that it controls the next `<div>`. I have multiple divs in some of the tabs on my full site, and I noticed this would result in it not working (as it didn't). Is this script able to influence the class of only the `<div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade in" id="about">`? Thank you for sticking with this question, you've been a great help so far.

Comment: Check [this](https://bitbucket.org/hnhm/tabs) repo @Jake, as I don't have your code is very difficult to say if it satisfies all what you need in your own project,

Comment: I checked out the repo, but I made the edits to my question to include what I'm up against in regards to the `<div>` situation. I am using various divs inside each of the tab-pane divs to do certain things. I'm not sure if this helps but I thought I would bring it up in case it is affecting the code. Thanks again @Sebastián Palma.

Answer (score 1):

Posting my solution here in case someone needs it.

I wanted to have a default option in case there was no parameter. I am using [Bootstrap's Navs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/components/navs/).

```
# Passing a params on 'link_to' method

# View with links

<%= link_to "Tab Index", tabs_path %>
<%= link_to "Tab 1", tabs_path(tab: 'tab_1') %>
<%= link_to "Tab 2", tabs_path(tab: 'tab_2') %>
<%= link_to "Tab 3", tabs_path(tab: 'tab_3') %>
```

```
# Adding 'active' class to navs based on params

# View with tabs

<%# Tabs %>
<ul class="nav nav-pills">
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a href="#tab_index" data-toggle="tab" role="tab" class="nav-link <%= "active" unless params.has_key?(:tab) %>">Tab Index</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a href="#tab_1" data-toggle="tab" role="tab" class="nav-link <%= "active" if params[:tab] == "tab_1" %>">Tab 1</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a href="#tab_2" data-toggle="tab" role="tab" class="nav-link <%= "active" if params[:tab] == "tab_2" %>">Tab 2</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a href="#tab_3" data-toggle="tab" role="tab" class="nav-link <%= "active" if params[:tab] == "tab_3" %>">Tab 3</a>
  </li>
</ul>

<%# Tab content %>
<div class="tab-content">
  <div class="tab-pane <%= "active" unless params.has_key?(:tab) %>" id="tab_index">Tab Index Content</div>
  <div class="tab-pane <%= "active" if params[:tab] == "tab_1" %>" id="tab_1">Tab 1 Content</div>
  <div class="tab-pane <%= "active" if params[:tab] == "tab_2" %>" id="tab_2">Tab 2 Content</div>
  <div class="tab-pane <%= "active" if params[:tab] == "tab_3" %>" id="tab_3">Tab 3 Content</div>
</div>
```